# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The ["graduation" election](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/election/1) for Craft CMS Stack Exchange has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: cherrykoda]

[image: Jalen Davenport]

[image: Brad Bell]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking [the site's pro-tem moderators](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) who've been on the site since it began:

[image: Anna_MediaGirl]

[image: Lindsey D]

[image: Matt Stein]

They've moderated the site for almost 9 years since it went into public beta in 2014! The site wouldn't be where it is today without them.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4527716467474432).

Comment: Thank you, it's been a true honor to serve as a moderator during these key years of growth in our community! Big congrats to our talented group of new moderators, welcome to the team Shawna, Jalen, and Brad!

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for everything, Lindsey, Matt, and Anna!

Comment: Thanks all - we'll try to keep it in the great shape we've found it!

Comment: I hope this Craft SE site continues to be an active resource for Craft developers. It's been invaluable to me as I do my work. Thank you Lindsey and Matt for sharing the moderating duties for the past nine years with me!! And thank you to Shawna, Jalen, and Brad for stepping up to take over for us ❤️